# Which scholarships should be on my CV?

Tags: graduate-admissions, funding, cv

I am dressing up my CV for graduate school admissions (Asian studies). I have included my merit-based scholarships in "Awards." However, is it also appropriate to list scholarships that I have been awarded that are judged based on financial need? Most of those also judge academic merit as a factor (though it is given less weight based on financial aid), and some of the need-based ones are considered competitive due to the ratio of awards to applicants.

I guess what I'm worried about is, does it disclose too much information about my financial situation--information which could bias an admissions committee against me?

Answer (score 2):

I would not recommend listing non-merit scholarships on an application unless the admissions office requires it for some reason.  They are simply orthogonal to your intellectual achievements, and thus do not generally belong on a C.V.

Note, however, that some non-merit scholarships do come with accompanying *jobs*, e.g., via work-study programs.  It may be appropriate to list such employment on your C.V. if it has anything to do with the goal you are aiming at.

Comment: Don't you think that even non-merit scholarships still show initiative, drive, resourcefulness, and the ability to compellingly argue (in the application)?

Comment: @schester If you have applied for them separately in a competitive process, then they could be listed under "funding secured."  When I was writing this, however, I was thinking about need-based scholarships, which many are, which don't demonstrate anything in particular.